# Webpage about to closed (probably) event?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I was reading [this article](http://www.mytreadmilltrainer.com/interval-running.html) in google-chrome and when I moved mouse to the close icon(x) on tab, web page displayed me a popup to wait, so my question is how do webpage knows I am going to close this tab, which javascript event it is?

Comment: Pretty annoying if you ask me. I would never return to your site if you push things into my face, when I want to use even the browser's toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's this [script](http://www.mytreadmilltrainer.com/action-popup/actionpopup.php). And by using this [deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10345/). You can see its source, and I'm guessing this is what you're looking for.

```
function handleMove(e) {
    if (e.clientY < lastY && e.clientY <= 10) {
        ActionPopup.show();
    }
    lastY = e.clientY;
}
```

[Script Source](http://pastebin.com/ybghpVrF)

Comment: yes, its simple, mouse tracking, i think there is some new javascript event :(

Comment: Facebook does this (sometimes, in error) "You've not finished your post yet - do you want to leave this page?"  - but, and this is crucial, it doesn't do it **until** you actually click on the close button.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively have a div, absolutely positioned across the top or just across the top right. OnmouseOver show the popup.